# How to remove the parent with nested inside? Firebase Realtime Database + Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to delete "temp".

[image: Imgur]

What is the best, and cleanest way of going about this?

According to the firebase real-time database docs, the best way to do this is using "remove()" but I always get the error, "Property 'remove' does not exist on type 'DataSnapshot'."

Comment: Welcome to SO! It may be helpful to share some of your code. You can delete a specific property with something like 
 this: `firebase.database().ref("/users/user209103/name").remove();`, see also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49149554/deleting-all-files-in-a-firebase-folder It seems, `.remove()` works on a file or folder.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.